# Backup bootable USB flash in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, unix, disk-space, bsd

I have a bootable USB. It runs Linux. The size of USB pen is 8Gb, and linux partitions take less than 200Mb.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ZigguratSSD             238.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.1 GB     disk2
   1:                      Linux                         16.4 MB    disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         98.7 MB    disk2s2
```

I would like to make a backup image of this pen.

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
$ sudo dd of=bckup.img if=/dev/disk2 bs=512
15769600+0 records in
15769600+0 records out
8074035200 bytes transferred in 1132.003040 secs (7132521 bytes/sec)
```

This way I get 8Gb backup file. Is there a way to reduce size of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compress the image as a `.zip` or `.tar`. Alternatively, if you use OS X's disk utilities to image it as a `.dmg`, that format includes compression.

---

If you're wanting to image just the partitions (and not raw, unpartitioned space at the end of the drive), then you might be able to simply limit how much dd copies by using the `count` parameter. Look at the end sector for the 2nd partition, and use `bs=<sector size>` and `count=<end sector>`

Comment: Captain Obvious :)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to truncate unneeded data.

Comment: If the partitions are located at the front of the disk and the remainder of the disk is raw, unformatted, unpartitioned space, you might be able to simply limit how much `dd` copies by using the `count` parameter. Look at the end sector for the 2nd partition, and use `bs=<sector size>` and `count=<end sector>`

Comment: Here is the command that worked for me: $ sudo dd of=bckup.img if=/dev/disk2 bs=512 count=248320. @Darth Android, Could you please send this a separate answer? I'd like to grant it to you.

Comment: @Antonio I just added it to this answer.